# iphone detect shake throughout app

Tags: ios, iphone, motion-detection

I need to have a function that detects a shake without having to add the `- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in every viewController.
But when I add the function to the appDelegate, the motion isn't detected.
I tried `NSNotificationCenter` to no avail. I have ton's of viewControllers and adding the motionEnded-method to all of them would be tedious…

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event in the AppDelegate.window.

ps:
subclass the UIWindow

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseViewController, put your shake detection methods there and make every controller inherit from it.